# Android: Fragment inside Activity. NullPointerException when getting View from Fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

Users have a crash. I know why but I do not know how to fix it. I am newbie in android dev.

Situation:
Android: Fragment inside Activity. Fragment has an EditText. Activity has a button. User tap the button. Inside Button.OnClick() I want to get text  Fragment.EditText.getText();
Some users have a crash here EditText.getText(). i.e. EditText is null.

How I do:

```
In Activity:
public class MyAcrivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    final MyFrag myFrag= MyFrag.newInstance();

    public void run(final View view) {
         //some users have crash here because getEt() return null
        final String str = myFrag.getEt().getText().toString(); 
    }

}
```

In Fragment:

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {

    private EditText et;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfrag, container, false);
        et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et);
    }

    public EditText getEt() {
        // return (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.et); here getView() could be nul too
        return et;
    }


}
```

- I know getView() could be null (already googled it).
- Init "View" inside onCreateView useless. Crash still happend.
- Init "View" inside onViewCreated useless. Crash still happend.

I can NOT reproduce this crash in emulator or my smartphone. I have stable work of my app. BUT some users have the crash and Fabric(crashlytics) is sending messages about it.

People! Help! How to obtain some View from Fragment correctly? I can not to find answers from lifecycle of Fragment. Please explain to me what is wrong.

Comment: Have you considered the [Fragment-Activity lifecycle relationship](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YJSE-iQngrw/U3bLHPnB1YI/AAAAAAAABWs/CD03Kp6O-zM/s1600/fragmentlifecycle.png)? You will need to check that you are not trying to access the `EditText` inside your `Fragment` before `onStart()` is called in your `Activity`, to ensure that it has been initialised.

Comment: When will u be calling run() method. because if you are calling the run() in onCreate() of activity then it returns null because fragment would not have been created.

Comment: Please specify where you are calling run() from?

Comment: run() is onClickEvent of button indise activity: <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabRun"
        android:onClick="run"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use [butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) like this:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @Bind(R.id.user) EditText username;
  @Bind(R.id.pass) EditText password;

  @BindString(R.string.login_error)
  String loginErrorMessage;

  @OnClick(R.id.submit) void submit() {
// TODO call server...
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
}
```

Comment: btw,Init "View" inside onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

From your  code it seems you have only created instance of fragment and trying to access the view .But to get the view of the  fragment you have to add fragment  to your activity.

Do this in your activity

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 
MyFrag myFrag= MyFrag();
ft.replace("YOUR_FRAGMENT_CONTAINER's id", myFrag);  
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunge, try to do the `newInstance()` call in the activity lifecycle. Otherwise, there might not be a trustable context to attach fragments. Try to do so in the `onCreate()`.

And something that might be unrelated, but did you properly attach that fragment to the activity? Chances are you are already doing, since *some users* are correctly accessing it. Anyway, here's the [fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html), and a code block to attach it.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment myFrag = MyFrag.newInstance();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add the fragment to the Activity in `Activity.onCreate()` method.
- Get the reference to the Activity during `Fragment.onAttach (Context)` in the Fragment.
- Create a method in Activity like enableButton(), which will enable the button like `button.setEnabled (true)`.
- Call this method from Fragment `onCreateView` after initializing the `EditText`.

This way you can ensure that `EditText` is initialized before the button is clicked.

Also remember to make the Activity reference null in `Fragment.onDetach`() to prevent any leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **getActivity.findViewById** in Fragment.

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {

    private EditText et;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfrag, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        et = (EditText) getActivity.findViewById(R.id.et);
    }

    public EditText getEt() {
        // return (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.et); here getView() could be nul too
        return et;
    }
}
```